# "strange" virtual memory chunks

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, embedded-linux

I have an ARM 32bit C/C++ program running on Ubuntu 14.04. The max resident memory of the program is about 90MB. However, the virtual memory size of the program is huge - around 400MB. I use pmap with x switch to check the details, what I find and don't quite understand is there are about 20-30 virtual memory chunks, each chunk's size is 8188KB and mode is RWX. The actual resident size of each 8188KB chunk is very small, something like 8K, 12KB, 24KB. Below is a snapshot for your reference.

```
Address   Kbytes     RSS   Dirty Mode  Mapping
00010000      12      12       0 r-x-- theApp
00022000       4       4       4 r---- theApp
00023000       4       4       4 rw--- theApp
00024000    3556    3536    3536 rw---   [ anon ]
9941c000       4       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
9941d000    8188       8       8 rwx--   [ anon ]
99c1c000       4       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
99c1d000    8188       8       8 rwx--   [ anon ]
9a41c000       4       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
9a41d000    8188       8       8 rwx--   [ anon ]
9ac1c000       4       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
9ac1d000    8188       8       8 rwx--   [ anon ]
9b41c000       4       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
9b41d000    8188       8       8 rwx--   [ anon ]
9bc1c000       4       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
9bc1d000    8188      24      24 rwx--   [ anon ]
...
b57f6000      28      28      28 rw--- libcrypto.so.1.0.0
b57fd000      12       4       4 rw---   [ anon ]
b5800000       4       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
b5801000    8188      12      12 rwx--   [ anon ]
...
```

In GDB, there is no information after I run - info symbol "the chunk's address". I also dump(dump memory command) some chunks into a file, each bit is zero.

In the program, there is no direct call to mmap. It only explicitly calls malloc and new for heap memory allocation. And I don't find any memory allocation size is 8188KB. Actually, I could identify each heap allocation of my code from the output of pmap. Of course, the program also uses some 3rd party shared libraries which I don't know the internal implementation.

My questions are:

1. where may the memory chunks come from?
2. is there any other ways to trace them down?
3. if swap file of the system is disabled, will the program still running fine? As the actual physical RAM is less than 400MB.

Any input will be appreciated!

Thanks,
-Neil

Comment: 8MB mappings might be for thread stacks - is your code multi-threaded ?

Comment: Good point! Yes, it's multithreaded. I may reduce stack size to confirm it. One more thing is that I find there are 40 8MB-chunks via pmap, but at that time there are only 28 running threads via GDB (info threads). Where could the 12 8MB-chunks be from?

Comment: might it be that 40 was the high-water mark for number of threads running at the same time ?

Comment: The `-----` pages are guard pages, on most Linux systems located just below a stack (since on most systems, stacks grow down, towards smaller addresses). So, the 9941c000 to 9bc1d000, and b5800000 and b5801000, are definitely stacks with their associated guard pages. I don't know why they're `rwx--` instead of `rw---`, though.

Comment: (When creating pthreads, I do recommend using `pthread_attr_t attrs; pthread_attr_init(&attrs); pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attrs, STACKSIZE);` with STACKSIZE being a power of two, say 32768 or 65536, to create an attribute set (to be used in one or more `pthread_create()` calls) specifying the stack size. It is not "consumed" by the pthread_create() call, it is only used as a definition on how the thread is to be created. After creating the thread or threads, you can use `pthread_attr_destroy(&attrs);` to destroy the attribute set. It won't affect any of the created threads at all.)

Comment: Thank you for all the comments. Those memory chunks are thread stack indeed. The only thing that I also could not explain is why they are RWX

Comment: afaik, it's less common now than it used to be to have the stack mappings executable, but there are some cases that need it. Relevant : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/Roadmap/ExecutableStacks

Comment: The program does not have executable stacks, but one of its dependency( a 3rd party SO) has, so that explains why the entire process's stacks are all RWE.  Thanks for the reference, Sander.